# UML: разница между черным и белыми ромбами при наследовании класса в диаграммах

Tags: наследование, uml, классы

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем разница между черным и белыми ромбами при наследовании класса в диаграммах UML?

[image: alt]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Незакрашенный ромб - отношение аггрегации. Агрегация - это отношение целое часть.

- агрегат (`MyEntityClass`) может существовать как независимо от частей (`MyClass`), так и вместе с ними;
- части могут существовать независимо от агрегата
- агрегат является в некотором смысле неполным в случае отсутствия частей
- части могут принадлежать одновременно нескольким агрегатам

Закрашенный ромб - композиция. Композиция - это строгая форма агрегации.

- Одновременно части (`MyClass2`) могут принадлежать только одному композиту (`MyEntityClass`) - совместное владение частями невозможно.
- композит обладает исключительной ответственностью за все свои части; это значит что он отвечает за их создание и уничтожение
- композит может высвобождать части, передавая ответственность за них другому объекту
- в случае уничтожения композита он должен уничтожить все свои части или передать ответственность за них другому объекту.

Ключевое различие композиции и агрегации в том что в композиции у частей нет независимой жизни вне целого (композита) Более того в композиции каждая часть принадлежит максимум одному и только одному целому (композиту), тогда как при агрегации часть может совместно использоваться несколькими целыми(агрегатами).

Д. Арлоу, А. Нейштадт - "UML2 и унифицированный процесс"

Comment: Оу, сложно...

Если вас не затруднит, приведите, пожалуйста, пример одного и другого на каком-нибудь языке, можно даже на псевдокоде.